# C6262 stack exceeds warning in c++ when using ofstream in file

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, heap-memory

For practice purposes, I tried creating a console app that will store basic information of employees and store it in a text file called employee-info.txt. I was able to write data in the text file but everytime the program writes new data, the C6262 warning appears. The warning can be seen in the function called employeeDataChecker() and employeeWriteData() under Employee.cpp, which I will indicate the codes below.

For employeeDataChecker(), the warning states that function uses '22800' bytes of stack: exceeds/analyze:stacksize'16384'. Consider moving some data to heap. For employeeWriteData, it has the same warning but larger bytes of stack '23264'. I even tried adding pointers in the arrays I integrated in the code, but it mess up my code even more.

Kindly advice and some guidance on how to manage this or provide me with a better solution in achieving my goal. You can also pinpoint bad practices that I made, so that I can learn from it to improve my code. The code I provided below is long but I'm still working on it everyday to minimize the code.

**Currently, this is the data stored in employee-info.txt:**

```
       ID           Firstname            Lastname                 Sales
        1              Dwyane             Anthony             250000.00
        2              Joseph            Cardinal             450000.00
        4               Bruno                Mars             250000.00
```

**This is the code for Employee.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

class Employee
{
public:
struct EmployeeRecord {
    static const int recordSize = 100;
    static const int fieldSize = 4;
    std::string record[recordSize][fieldSize];
};

public:
Employee();
~Employee();
void employeeDataChecker();
void employeeWriteData(int recordCount, std::string recordCopy[EmployeeRecord::recordSize][EmployeeRecord::fieldSize]);
void employeeDisplayData();
EmployeeRecord& employeeReturnRecordArray();

private:
EmployeeRecord emp_record;

};
```

**And here is the code in Employee.cpp:**

```
void Employee::employeeDataChecker() {
//Check if there are data in the employee-info.txt
EmployeeRecord emp;
std::ifstream inFile, inFile2;
int recordCount = 0;
inFile.open("C:\\Users\\RJ\\Desktop\\employee-info.txt"); // use to get the number of values stored in record array
inFile2.open("C:\\Users\\RJ\\Desktop\\employee-info.txt"); // use to get all contents in record array

for (int index = 0; index < emp.recordSize; index++) {
    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < emp.fieldSize; index2++) {
        while (inFile >> emp.record[index][index2]) {
            recordCount++;
        }
    }
}

for (int index = 0; index < emp.recordSize; index++) {
    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < emp.fieldSize; index2++) {
        inFile2 >> emp.record[index][index2];
    }
}
//used as a dummy array to hold the values in record array and pass as an argument 
std::string recordCopy[emp.recordSize][emp.fieldSize];


    for (int index = 0; index < emp.recordSize; index++) {
        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < emp.fieldSize; index2++) {
            recordCopy[index][index2] = emp.record[index][index2];
        }
    }



inFile.close();
inFile2.close();

employeeWriteData(recordCount, recordCopy);
}//end of employeeDataChecker

void Employee::employeeWriteData(int recordCount, std::string recordCopy[EmployeeRecord::recordSize][EmployeeRecord::fieldSize]) {
Employee emp;
EmployeeRecord empRec;
int numEmployees;
std::string firstName, lastName;
std::string fullName = "";
double sales;

std::ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("C:\\Users\\RJ\\Desktop\\employee-info.txt", std::ofstream::app);

//pass all values from recordCopy to record array
for (int index = 0; index < empRec.recordSize; index++) {
    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < empRec.fieldSize; index2++) {
        empRec.record[index][index2] = recordCopy[index][index2];
    }
}

std::cout << "------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Enter The Number of Employees to Add: ";
std::cin >> numEmployees;
std::cin.get();

if (recordCount == 0) {

    //If employee-info.txt is empty.
    outFile << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setprecision(2);
    outFile << std::setw(5) << "ID";
    outFile << std::setw(20) << "Firstname";
    outFile << std::setw(20) << "Lastname";
    outFile << std::setw(22) << "Sales" << std::endl;

    for (int index = 0; index < numEmployees; index++) {
        int empID = index;
        empID++;
        std::cout << "*****Employee ID No." << empID << "*****" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter First Name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, firstName);
        std::cout << "Enter Last Name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, lastName);
        fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

        std::cout << "Enter Total Sales: ";
        std::cin >> sales;

        std::string empIDConverted = std::to_string(empID);
        std::string salesConverted = std::to_string(sales);

        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < empRec.fieldSize; index2++) {
            if (index2 == 0) {
                empRec.record[index][index2] = empIDConverted;
            }
            else if (index2 == 1) {
                empRec.record[index][index2] = firstName;
            }
            else if (index2 == 2) {
                empRec.record[index][index2] = lastName;
            }
            else if (index2 == 3) {
                empRec.record[index][index2] = salesConverted;
            }
        }

        outFile << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setprecision(2);
        int numSetW;
        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < empRec.fieldSize; index2++) {

            if (index2 == 0) {
                numSetW = 5;
            }
            else if(index2 == 3){
                numSetW = 22;
            }
            else {
                numSetW = 20;
            }

            if (index2 == (empRec.fieldSize - 1)) {

                std::string getSales = empRec.record[index][index2];
                double salesPreviousType;
                std::istringstream iss(getSales);
                iss >> salesPreviousType;

                outFile << std::setw(numSetW) << salesPreviousType << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                outFile << std::setw(numSetW) << empRec.record[index][index2];
            }
        }
        std::cin.get();
    }

}
else if (recordCount >= empRec.fieldSize) {
    //If employee-info.txt already has an existing data. It will write new data at the end of record array.

    int rows = recordCount / empRec.fieldSize;
    int increasedFieldSize = empRec.fieldSize * 2;
    int preIndex = rows;

    for (int index = rows; index < (numEmployees + preIndex); index++) {
        int empID = index;
        empID++;
        std::cout << "*****Employee ID No." << empID << "*****" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter First Name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, firstName);
        std::cout << "Enter Last Name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, lastName);
        fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

        std::cout << "Enter Total Sales: ";
        std::cin >> sales;

        std::string empIDConverted = std::to_string(empID);
        std::string salesConverted = std::to_string(sales);

        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < empRec.fieldSize; index2++) {
            if (index2 == 0) {
                empRec.record[index][index2] = empIDConverted;
            }
            else if (index2 == 1) {
                empRec.record[index][index2] = firstName;
            }
            else if (index2 == 2) {
                empRec.record[index][index2] = lastName;
            }
            else if (index2 == 3) {
                empRec.record[index][index2] = salesConverted;
            }
        }

        outFile << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setprecision(2);
        int numSetW;
        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < empRec.fieldSize; index2++) {

            if (index2 == 0) {
                numSetW = 5;
            }
            else if (index2 == 3) {
                numSetW = 22;
            }
            else {
                numSetW = 20;
            }

            if (index2 == (empRec.fieldSize - 1)) {

                std::string getSales = empRec.record[index][index2];
                double salesPreviousType;
                std::istringstream iss(getSales);
                iss >> salesPreviousType;

                outFile << std::setw(numSetW) << salesPreviousType << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                outFile << std::setw(numSetW) << empRec.record[index][index2];
            }

        }
        std::cin.get();
    }

}
else {
    std::cout << "Number problem!";
}


outFile.close();
  }//end of employeeWriteData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EmployeeRecord` structure is quite big for allocation on stack because of static 100x4 `std::string` array. Allocate the array or the `EmployeeRecord` instance dynamically to eliminate that warning.

The same is for `std::string recordCopy[emp.recordSize][emp.fieldSize];`.